# css box layout overflow the screen height

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

i want a screen like this image
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq3sv.png) ,

height row div, no overflow, that contains:

1. a left box that contains as a column:

   - a header with a fixed hight 20px,
   - an aspect square box based on the remaining height.
2. middle bar width 20px h-screen, and
3. a right-side panel also h-screen and takes remaining screen width
   use tailwind.

i keep trying but always the board overflows the screen height.
here is what i tried.

```
<div className="flex h-screen">
      <div className="flex-col">
        <Header/>
        <div className="flex-grow bg-red-500 aspect-square">
         <Board/> 
      </div>
      </div>

      <div className=" flex-initial">
        <ControlBar />
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-1">
        <div className="w-full flex-grow flex-col justify-between">
          <Panel />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code snippet should be what you're after.

Tailwind doesn't have a built-in class to cover calculated height values with regards to pixel values, but vanilla CSS does:

```
style="height: calc(100vh - 20px);"
```

This styling calculates the height of the viewport and then subtracts 20px from the total dynamically. See this in action below:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex h-screen">
    <div class="flex flex-col bg-blue-500">
      <div class="h-20 bg-yellow-300">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="aspect-square bg-green-300" style="height: calc(100vh - 20px);">
        Aspect Square Box
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="w-20 bg-gray-400">
        Middle Bar
      </div>
      <div class="flex-1 bg-red-500">
        Right-side Panel
      </div>
  </div>
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Sorry but your snippet is based on giving the left div w-1/2 which is not desirable and not responsive; and if i remove the w-1/2 and the surrounding div as you said the square div takes as its inner content which is not what i want, i want the square box to have the height of remaining screen height

Comment: I edited the answer to accommodate your clarified desired result. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: actually, its better thank you but what if i want the header to take whatever height its content takes